# Check this proof about seq. compact pre-image

Tags: real-analysis

I've been thinking about this problem for a while and I think I have a good proof but I feel weak in these areas so I was hoping for some helpful criticism.

Proposition: Suppose that the function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and that $f(\vec u) \geq \|\vec u\|$ for all points $u \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that the pre-image $f^{-1}([0,1])$ is sequentially compact.

Proof: We recall that a set is sequentially compact if and only if it is closed and bounded. Let $U = f^{-1}([0,1])$. Let $u \in U$. By our assumption, $0 \leq \|u\| \leq f(u) \leq 1$, where the bounds come from the fact that our image $f([0,1])$ is itself a closed bounded interval. We can see from the previous inequality that $0 \leq \|u\| \leq 1$. So since the norms of all the points in our set $U$ are bounded, by the definition of a bounded set, $U$ is bounded.

Now we want to show that $U$ is closed. Let $\{v_k\}$ be a sequence of points contained in $U$ that converges to $v$. We will show (or attempt to anyway) that $v$ is in our set $U$.

Since all the points in the sequence $\{v_k\}$ are in the set $U$, we have that $0 \leq \|v_k\| \leq f(v_k) \leq 1$. Now, since by assumption the sequence is convergent, if we take the limit as $k \to \infty$, we get that

$$0 \leq \|v\| \leq f(v) \leq 1$$

Which means that $v \in U$. Therefore, the set $U = f^{-1}([0,1])$ is closed and is therefore sequentially compact.

Q.E.D.

Comments: I was a little unsure of whether at the end I could assert that $v$ meeting those requirements meant that $v$ had to be in $U$. Since I don't know anything about the function, what if the sequence is converging to a point in some other set that possibly gets mapped into the interval $([0,1])$. I suppose this is taken care of by the fact that I assumed that my sequence was contained solely in $U$.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: For future reference, if $K$ is closed and $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(K)$ is always closed. In fact that can be taken as the definition of continuous.

Comment: Sequentially compact and compact are equivalent in $\mathbb{R}^n$, are they not?

Comment: Also it's simpler and more clear to say: Since $f$ is continuous, and $\lim v_k = v$, $\lim f(v_k)=f(v)$. But $f(v_k)$ is then a convergent sequence in $[0,1]$, so its limit must be in $[0,1]$ since the closed interval is sequentially compact, so $f(v)\in [0,1]$ which implies $v\in U$ by definition.

Comment: **jgon**'s comment is how I would have done it as well. However, your argument is correct: no other points are mapped into $[0,1]$, because $U$ is the entire inverse image of $[0,1]$ under $f$.

Comment: @Vinícius: Yes, they are.

Comment: @jgon. I thought that one definition of continuity is that if $K$ is open, and $f$ is continuous, then $f^{-1}(K)$ is always open. I didn't think it worked for closed sets. If I took $f:(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$, to be the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}$. Is that not a continuous function that maps the open set $(0,1)$ to the closed set $[\frac{1}{2}]$? Sorry if I misunderstood your comment, but I just want to make sure because I have finals coming up soon and this is an important concept for me to understand.

Comment: @Mathematacticool Well that's because $(1,2)$ is closed in the relative topology on $(1,2)$ since it is equal to $[1,2]\cap(1,2)$. You always have to work with the topology on the domain of your function.